# Format a column of prices in CSV in R

Tags: r, price

I have a csv file, where the prices after exported in R as a list, are worded like: $115.00 USD, so I cannot convert it with

```
as.numeric(sub('\\$','',as.character(Data)))
```

because it returns with N/As because of the " USD" part.

Comment: we need more details and what is your question?

Comment: "Sub" out the dollar sign and USD: `as.numeric( gsub("[$]|USD","", '$115.00 USD') )`

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to just remove everything that isn't a number or period:

```
> gsub("[^0-9.]", "", "$115.00 USD")
[1] "115.00"
```

If you want to ensure that you have a contiguous string of characters from the input, you can use a capture:

```
> sub("[^0-9.]*([0-9.]*).*", "\\1", "$115.00 USD")
[1] "115.00"
```